# File shows up when I do a listing of my current working directory but says it does not exist if I try to do anything with it

Tags: aix

I'm working with an AIX server. I created a file, ucm.txt, today. Now I am done with the file and would like to remove it.

If I do `ls -ltr` in my current directory, I get this.

`-rw-r--r--    1 barringer  myserver          11729 Jul 16 09:11 ucm.txt`

If I try to do anything with the file (have not changed directories), I get this.

=> rm ucm.txt

`rm: ucm.txt: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.`

=> more ucm.txt

`ucm.txt: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.`

Comment: are you referencing the right directory or executing the command from the right directory?  `rm /file/location/ucm.txt` is not the same as `rm ucm.txt`

Comment: What does ls -lq show you?

Comment: => ls -ltr       -rw-r--r--    1 maaduser  maad          11729 Jul 16 09:11 ucm.txt

Comment: => ls -ltr     `-rw-r--r--    1 barringer  myserver          11729 Jul 16 09:11 ucm.txt`

=> ls -lq     `-rw-r--r--    1 barringer  myserver          11729 Jul 16 09:11 ucm.txt?`

=> cat ucm.txt     `cat: cannot open ucm.txt`


=> more ucm.txt     `ucm.txt: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely there are "bad characters" or empty spaces in the file name

you can try this:

ls -1 | while read file
do
   ls -lsd "$file"
done 
See if the "ls" can find the file. If it can, you can adjust this script to remove the file. 
Be careful though: this piece of script I provided is listing ALL files in the directory, if you adjust it to remove the file, make sure it will just rm the file you want.